# FIll two dimensional array

Tags: java

I need to enter into the DATA variable values fetched from another logic in a loop .basically does not want it to be static .

```
private static final Object[][] DATA = {
    {"One", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Two", Boolean.FALSE},
    {"Three", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Four", Boolean.FALSE},
    {"Five", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Six", Boolean.FALSE},
    {"Seven", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Eight", Boolean.FALSE},
    {"Nine", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Ten", Boolean.FALSE}};
```

This is what I did , will it fill data as prescribed above

```
      for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
               DATA[i][1]=nodeList.item(i).getNodeName() + ":" +  nodeList.item(i).getTextContent();    
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use Map instead of array?

Comment: It is static, because it is final. It points out that your array is stable and static say that it is not belong on specific object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your static example the object type is String and Boolean.
so you have to parse the second value to Boolean.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
           DATA[i][0]=nodeList.item(i).getNodeName() ;    
           DATA[i][0]=Boolean.parseBoolean(nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());  
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but still finding it hard to populate the DATA variable.
Can I use an Array

Comment: i dont know what you mean with "populate the DATA variable"